# DCWebGL Slider doesn't find light.hdr file

Tags: html

I downloaded the DCWebGL Slider and when i initialise it i become an error that the light.hdr file couldn't be found.

I tried a other Preset but the problem was the same

body {
                margin:0;
            }
            #SliderDiv .dcwgls-slide-title {
                font-family: 'Raleway';
                font-size: 60px; 
                color: #d1dd27; 
                text-align: right;
            }
            #SliderDiv .dcwgls-slide-subtitle {
                font-family: 'Open Sans'; 
                font-size: 40px;
                color: #fff; 
                text-align: right;
            }
        
    
    
        
            
                
                Cat
                XD

Sorry for this
                XD

```
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="codecanyon-ciI94Pzf-dcwebgl-slider-real-3d-jquery-plugin/jquery-dcwebgl-slider/src/jquery.dcwebglslider.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            $('#SliderDiv').dcWebglSlider({
                envPreset: 'glass_passage'
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem, the problem was that the server doesn't had allowed the hdr files.
I changed this at the server and the problem was solved